# Drupal search module has suddenly stopped working, how do I fix this problem?

Tags: php, search, drupal, drupal-6

Drupal 6.15 search has stopped working. how can I fix it? I've run the cron and re-indexed, but it still does nothing when searching. Any ideas? I can see the tables that the items have been indexed, but search results show a blank white page.

Comment: what's in you error log?

Comment: 'a blank page' as in 'no search results' or as in 'not even a single pixel'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "blank page" you mean completely white, then that usually means there's an error that's being hidden from view. Put this at the very beginning of your index.php (to enable error reporting):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

And then try the search. Chances are you'll see the error message, and that will tell you what's going on.

If all else fails, flush all caches and run update.php just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. The problem was with one of my modules, Thank you Mike, silly me. I didn't remember the damn display errors setting. Thanks again.

- Oh the module was the phonetic module

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are not including a functions file that contains a function with the same name as something in the search module.  In my case, I have a function library that I use for all of my database apps with a function named `Do_Search()`.  Since I don't output error messages to the screen, I didn't see that PHP was squawking because the function was being used twice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my blog. Maybe this case helps someone.

Unfortunately neither error displayed on blank page. Despiete I turned on all flag and php configuration.

The problem was in some my custom module that try to "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at "

Try to find this error message.